# Cant display data from database php - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot display data from my database and I have no idea why, all I'm trying to do is display the id and username near the bottom, the connection to the database works, it all works except displaying data, ive been stuck all day.
Please help! (I know I should be using mysqli but ill deal with that another time)

```
<?php
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "Username", "Pass");

$db = mysql_select_db("cl45-game", $connection);

$sql = "SELECT id, username FROM User";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["username"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$connection->close();

?>
```

Comment: Debug your code there must be some errors

Comment: may be there is no data in database at all to display.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing Object MySQLi and MySQL. Try this, and let me know if it works (currently on mobile, I apologize for any poor formatting)

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["username"]. "<br>";
     } 
} else { 
    echo "0 results";
} 
mysql_close($connection);
```

As you said yourself, you really should convert it to MySQLi or PDO to avoid SQL-injection! As is, you code has a huge security issue! You could also look into Sanitizing Filters.

Also, where is your 'WHERE' selector? Now it will return all id's and usernames (or is that what you intended?). Also it doesn't select by correct username or password. And as it was commented, are you sure you are querying the correct database, and that it has values to select?